# Release, debug version and Authorization Google?

Tags: android, debugging, authentication, release, google-authentication

**Here I downloaded the source code (tutorial from Google) authorization via Google.**

If you run a debug version everything works as planned. But if you install and run the release version, it does not work in the emulator or on a real phone.
Tell me what's the problem? Maybe the problem with SHA1. When I do "gradle" -> "signingReport".
I get the following:

```
Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: none
----------
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\******\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: <some code****>
SHA1: <some code*****>
Valid until: <date***>
----------
Variant: release
Config: none
----------
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\******\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: <some code****>
SHA1: <some code*****>
Valid until: <date***>
----------
Variant: debug
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\******\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: <some code****>
SHA1: <some code*****>
Valid until: <date***>
```

**Also, one person said about it the next thing:**

> The release version does not work because signed others certificate and its fingerprint you are not registered in Developer Console.

But I do not understand what it means.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like few months since this question asked but I will Answer It anyway If anyone ran in to same problem

You have to find    SHA1 code for   Release Key & enter it on your Developer Console. ( for me developer console is firebase  some people might use different services)   To find  SHA1 Code . easy way is

**Go to Build --- Select Build Variant   --  On the left Side  Select "Release" as build variant --  now go to module settings ( or try to run project , android studio will tell you about a error and  click fix error button) --- Select Signing tab --- add your release key and passwords --  now goto build types -- select  release -- on signing config  select your  release key config -- now run your project -- now run your   signing report  --- you can find SHA1 under release build -- enter that sha1 code on your developer console**

Comment: Thank you very much. That was long story.

Comment: For some reason, I see only "Config: debug" in my case here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75435486/878126 . Only when I commented the debug configurations, it showed release. Can you please tell me how come ?