# GPGS fails to sign in when download from PlayStore. Okay when install directly from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-games

Made a game with Libgdx and eventually got GPGS Leaderboard and Achievements to work. Or so I thought.

They run fine on my phone and tablet when I install the APK directly through Android Studio but it won't allow users to sign in when they have downloaded the game from Google Play Store.

`Failed to sign in. Please check your network connection and try again`

The SHA-1 matches in console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/ and gradle.

Leaderboards etc have all been published days ago.

What have I forgotten to do? Is there a new SHA-1 I should add to developer console that I don't know how to find? I'm "certain" I've covered all the basics illustrated in other questions on SO.

I am thinking/hoping it is something in the developer console I've forgotten/missed.

Here's AndroidLauncher though just in case I'm wrong about that, thanks in advance:

```
package com.weavernap.chuggydodge;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper;
import com.weavernap.cdHelpers.AdsController;


public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements GameHelper.GameHelperListener, AdsController {

    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

    private static final String BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3737397260010456/7958274520";

    private static final String INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3737397260010456/3314422124";

    protected AdView adView;
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    protected View gameView;

    private GameHelper gameHelper;
  //  private AdsController adsController;
   // private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;



    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private boolean writeLogs = true;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-3737397260010456~9090257326");

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();


        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1));
        AdView adView = this.createAdView();
        relativeLayout.addView(adView);
        relativeLayout.addView(this.createGameView(config));
        this.setContentView(relativeLayout);
        this.startAdvertising(adView);
        this.interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        this.interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID);


        if (this.gameHelper == null) {
            this.gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, 1);
            this.gameHelper.enableDebugLog(this.writeLogs);
        }
        this.gameHelper.setup(this);


//
//      // Create a gameView and a bannerAd AdView
//      View gameView = initializeForView(new CDGame(this), config);
//      setupAds();


//      // Define the layout
//      RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
//      layout.addView(gameView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
//              ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
//      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
//              ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
//              ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//      params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
//      layout.addView(bannerAd, params);
//
//      setContentView(layout);


    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        gameHelper.onStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        gameHelper.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
        gameHelper.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    }


    @Override
    public void showOrLoadInterstitial(final boolean showAd) {
        try {
            this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (AndroidLauncher.this.interstitialAd.isLoaded() && showAd) {
                        AndroidLauncher.this.interstitialAd.show();
                        return;
                    } //else
                    {
                        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                        AndroidLauncher.this.interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
                    }
                }
            });
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Gdx.app.log("ChuggerDodge.ERROR", "Exception in showOrLoadInterstitial:" + e.toString());
            return;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void submitScoreGPGS(int score) {
        if (this.getSignedInGPGS()) {
            Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(this.gameHelper.getApiClient(), this.getString(R.string.leaderboard_top_scores), score);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void unlockAchievementGPGS(int score) {

        if (this.getSignedInGPGS()) {
            if (score == 0) {
                Games.Achievements.unlock(this.gameHelper.getApiClient(),
                        this.getString(R.string.achievement_the_every_loser_wins_trophy));
            }
            if (score > 3) {
                Games.Achievements.unlock(this.gameHelper.getApiClient(),
                        this.getString(R.string.achievement_not_completely_useless));
            }
            if (score > 19) {
                Games.Achievements.unlock(this.gameHelper.getApiClient(),
                        this.getString(R.string.achievement_hey_youre_all_right_you_are_));
            }

            if (score == 42) {
                Games.Achievements.unlock(this.gameHelper.getApiClient(),
                        this.getString(R.string.achievement_the_hyperintelligent_pandimensional_being_prize));
            }

            if (score > 43) {
                Games.Achievements.unlock(this.gameHelper.getApiClient(),
                        this.getString(R.string.achievement_wowzers__youre_about_as_good_as_me_now_));
            }


            if (score > 76) {
                Games.Achievements.unlock(this.gameHelper.getApiClient(),
                        this.getString(R.string.achievement_actually_thats_quite_impressive_));
            }


        }


    }


    @Override
    public void getGPGSLeaderboard() {
        if (this.gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
            this.startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(this.gameHelper.getApiClient(), this.getString(R.string.leaderboard_top_scores)), 100);
            return;
        } else {
            if (this.gameHelper.isConnecting()) return;
            {
                this.loginGPGS();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getSignedInGPGS() {
        if (this.gameHelper != null) {
            System.out.println("Superduperdavid");
            return this.gameHelper.isSignedIn();
        }
        System.out.println("Nah");
        return false;
    }

//


    @Override
    public void loginGPGS() {
        //  if (!gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
        try {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
                }
            });
            return;
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            Gdx.app.log("MainActivity", "Log in failed: " + ex.getMessage() + ".");
            return;
        }
//
    }
//

    @Override
    public void getAchievementsGPGS() {
        //     if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient()), 101);
//        } else if (!gameHelper.isConnecting()) {
//            loginGPGS();
//        }
    }


    //Following from toaster code

    private AdView createAdView() {
        this.adView = new AdView(this);
        this.adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        this.adView.setAdUnitId(BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -2);
        layoutParams.addRule(12, -1);
        layoutParams.addRule(14, -1);
        this.adView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        this.adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        return this.adView;
    }

    private View createGameView(AndroidApplicationConfiguration androidApplicationConfiguration) {
        this.gameView = this.initializeForView(new CDGame(this), androidApplicationConfiguration);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -2);
        layoutParams.addRule(10, -1);
        layoutParams.addRule(14, -1);
        layoutParams.addRule(2, this.adView.getId());
        this.gameView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        return this.gameView;
    }

    private void startAdvertising(AdView adView) {
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (this.adView != null) {
            this.adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (this.adView != null) {
            this.adView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (this.adView != null) {
            this.adView.resume();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onSignInFailed() {
        gameHelper.getSignInError();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so at some point I had entered the debug SHA-1 into the developer console to get GPGS working during testing. But did not realise that you had to revert back to the original.

So following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39522981/6657630) and making the changes in the console did the trick pretty much straight away.